# EPPlus Copying multiple sheets into a single sheet with images

Tags: image, epplus

I am trying to copy a workbook with multiple sheets into a single sheet. I have found other libraries that work fine for copying ranges or sheets into the bottom of another but they don't copy the images. Is this possible with EPPlus? If it isn't are there other libraries that do this?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this accomplished by using GemBox.Spreadsheet. The were quite responsive to bug(s) in their library and it all functions correctly now.

Answer (score 0):

```
var excelDrawings = sheet1.Drawings.Where(x => x.DrawingType == 
eDrawingType.Picture).ToList();

foreach (var excelDrawing in excelDrawings)
{
    var name = excelDrawing.Name;
    var image = excelDrawing.As.Picture.Image;

    singleSheet.Drawings.AddPicture(name, image);
}
```